# Sharepoint Hosted Permission (SP 2013)

Tags: javascript, permissions, sharepoint-addin, sharepoint-hosted-app

I am developing a test REST app currently, the app is sharepoint hosted and is being developed and deployed to the SP site without Sharepoint installed on my Machine.

The app is meant to take in a query param that is a title of a list or a guid and search the SP site for the list and return the contents of the list.  Is set up the query call and generated the URLs correctly but when I requested Search permission within the App Manifest to be set to "QueryAsUserIgnoreAppPrincipal", upon deployment to the site I receive a prompt to trust the app with the error ***Sorry, only tennant administrators can add or give access to this app.***

The "Trust it" option cannot be selected, can anyone shed some light on this issue as to why I am getting this error?

-Thanks

Comment: Have you tried to set yourself as Site Collection administrator on the SPSite you try to deploy to? Also if this is for development you could try to enable the developer feature (simply `Enable-SPFeature Developer -Url <SPSite url>`

Comment: I have yet to test the developer feature, but I am currently a Site Collection Admin. What would enabling the dev feature change permission-wise?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some of the permissions like `Search` , `User Profile Service`, `Social Capabilities` etc, you need to be tenant admin and not just site collection admin.

For more details on this topic please check the following msdn articles

[App Permissions in SP 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/fp142383%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

[Search apps in SP 2013](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/dn554260%28v=office.15%29.aspx)

So basically, you need to login from tenant admin account and then "Trust" the app.

Comment: Okay, I'm just trying to rule out the fact that this could just be something I'm doing wrong.  In my app manifest I have cinluded the